# How to change code get image from a folder in github

Tags: python, github, heroku, discord.py

I made a discord bot in vsc and it works perfectly fine. I wanted it to be online without needing my computer on. I put my code in GitHub and hooked it up to Heroku. Everything is working the same expect when I ask for a image.

when I do **!help** it brings up the help menu. but when I do **!png box** nothing happens.
this was the code in vsc, when it was working(The code and images are in the same folder)

```
@client.command()
async def png(ctx, *, arg):
    if(arg == 'box'):
        await ctx.send(file=discord.File('box.png'))
```

Do I need to change the code or what do i have to do. The images are in a folder in GitHub called **items** how do I change the code so it works.

(This is also my first time using GitHub and Heroku so there might be a simple answer which I don't know and I'm also pretty new to coding as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the image is not available locally on Heroku you can send it from github. As the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-upload-an-image) indicates, you can make an HTTP request using aiohttp and then pass an io.BytesIO instance to File. Make sure you use the direct url to the image on github.

```
import io
import aiohttp

@client.command()
async def png(ctx, *, arg):
    if(arg == 'box'):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/your_github_name/your_repo_name/master/items/box.png") as resp:
                if resp.status != 200:
                    return await ctx.send('Could not download file...')
                data = io.BytesIO(await resp.read())
                await ctx.send(file=discord.File(data, 'box.png'))
```